# Can you change the search engines order in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

Can you change the search engines order (more specifically, the ones in the default settings tab) in Google Chrome?

I think they are in the order they were added to the default search engines tab, but they don't have to be. Because they are not ordered by name and not easy to look through at a glance, I sometimes unwittingly add a search engine that is already in there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Goto Settings in Chrome->Search

Then choose the search engine you want.

[image]

Comment: Read carefully, the question is not about changing the search engine.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still interested in changing the search engines order in Chrome, Opera or any other Chromium based Internet browser:

1. Close all instances of your Internet browser.
2. Find the "Web Data" file for your browser (MAKE A BACKUP). For Chrome this is found usually in "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default". It's a SQLite database.
3. Open the file with any database query tool (like the free "DB Browser for SQLite") and open the "keywords" table.
4. Change the order of items by modifying the "id" column (it's ordered by numbers).
5. Apply and save your changes.. then open your browser.